# How to submit form data to html5 local database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-database

I am writing this very small application to run on an iPod. It is meant to store information based on a workout that I enter in. The storage will be html5 local database. My question is how do I get the information from the form which has multiple exercises and create a new record for each exercise? The html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>lower</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="john" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="work.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.5; maximum-scale=0.6; minimum-scale=0.6; user-scalable=0;" />        
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Lower Body</h1>
        <div>
            <form method="post" id="workout_form">          
                <div>
                <table id="hipadd">
                    <label for="hipAddReps">Hip Adductor</label>
                    <tr><td>Seat <input type="text" id="hipAddSeatSetting" size="1"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Reps <input type="text" id="hipAddReps" size="2" value="10"/></td><td>Weight </td><td><input type="text" id="hipAddWeight" size="3" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div><br />
            <div>
                <table id="hipab">
                    <label for="hipAbReps">Hip Abductor</label>
                    <tr><td>Seat <input type="text" id="hipAbSeatSetting" size="1"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Reps <input type="text" id="hipAbReps" size="2" value="10"/></td><td>Weight </td><td><input type="text" id="hipAbWeight" size="3"/></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div><br />
            <div>
                <table id="legcurl">
                    <label for="legCurlReps">Leg Curl</label>
                    <tr><td>Back <input type="text" id="legCurlBackSetting" size="1"/></td><td>Feet </td><td><input type="text" id="legCurlFeetSetting" size="1"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Reps <input type="text" id="legCurlReps" size="2" value="10"/></td><td>Weight </td><td><input type="text" id="legCurlWeight" size="3"/></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div><br />
            <div>
                <table id="legext">
                    <label for="legExtensionReps">Leg Extension</label>
                    <tr><td>Back <input type="text" id="legExtensionBackSetting" size="1"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Reps <input type="text" id="legExtensionReps" size="2" value="10"/></td><td>Weight </td><td><input type="text" id="legExtensionWeight" size="3"/></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div><br />
            <div>
                <table id="legpress">
                    <label for="legPressReps">Leg Press</label>
                    <tr><td>Back <input type="text" id="legPressBackSetting" size="1"/></td><td>Seat </td><td><input type="text" id="legPressSeatSetting" size="1"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Reps <input type="text" id="legPressReps" size="2" value="10"/></td><td>Weight </td><td><input type="text" id="legPressWeight" size="3"/></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div><br />
            <div>
                <table id="glute">
                    <label for="gluteReps">Glute</label>
                    <tr><td>Seat <input type="text" id="gluteSeatSetting" size="1"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Reps <input type="text" id="gluteReps" size="2" value="10"/></td><td>Weight </td><td><input type="text" id="gluteWeight" size="3"/></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div><br />
            <div>
                <button type="button" onclick="insertData()">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and the JavaScript I have so far is

```
 $(function(){ initDatabase();

});

function initDatabase() {
    try {
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            alert('Local Databases are not supported by your browser.');
        } else {
            var shortName = 'WorkoutDB';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'Workout Database';
            var maxSize = 100000;
            db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            createTables();
        }
    } catch(e) {
        if (e == 2) {
            // Version mismatch.
            console.log("Invalid database version.");
        } else {
            console.log("Unknown error "+ e +".");
        }
        return;
    } 
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
        db.transaction(function (transaction) {
            //transaction.executeSql('drop table workout');
            transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workout(name TEXT, back TEXT, seat TEXT, feet TEXT, reps TEXT, weight TEXT);', [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler);
        }
    );
    //insertData();
 });

 function insertData(){
    var data = [$("label[for=hipAddReps]").text(), '', $('#hipAddSeatSetting').val(), '', $('#hipAddReps').val(), $('#hipAddWeight').val()];
        db.transaction(function (transaction) {         
            transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO Workout(Name, Back, Seat, Feet, Reps, Weight) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5]]);
    });
 }


function errorHandler(transaction, error){
    if (error.code==1){
        // DB Table already exists
    } else {
        // Error is a human-readable string.
        console.log('Oops.  Error was '+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
    }
    return false;
}


function nullDataHandler(){
    console.log("SQL Query Succeeded");
}
```

so what I want is to fill in all of the fields on this form and hit the submit button at the bottom and have a new record inserted for each exercise I have.

Comment: so are you saying that something like this answer is the only way?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2227399/1060248
essentially creating a new array and a new insert statement for every exercise?

Comment: you said you are making this application for an ipod, I assume since you are doing it in HTML5, there is some middle application which makes the app into IOS. Perhaps are you using [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) or [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)? More information would help answer the your question.

Comment: I am not at that point yet so I have not decided, do I need to decide that before I go further? I am just trying to get it working right then I was going to consider what I needed to do to get it on my iPod. Sorry if this is vague it is my first go around with this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going to make an application for the iOS (iPod), you would normally do this in objective C, however to do it in HTML5 you should look into a good framework. Take a look at Phonegap. They even have a [getting started guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS) to get you up and running quickly. An alternative is [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/), although its not entirely free.

If you want to save form data to your phone you will need to consider using a light weight database, or flat file storage.  Here is a link to [phonegap's storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html) recommendations.

Example:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
}

</script>
</head>
 <body>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <p>Open Database</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you would like a great book about iphone, ipod and iOS development I would recommend [Big Nerd Ranch's](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_rd_edition_) book, its a great first time book that walks you through all the red tape with apple's dev account setup.

Good luck, and I recommend re-posting your question with phonegap, and iOS tags to get more exposure.